# Which "spawn points" have helicopters in Ghost Recon Wildands?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I've been scouting GR Wildlands "cheat sheets", but honestly does anyone out there have a list of rebel hideouts I can spawn/travel to with a "free" chopper relatively nearby? Even if I have to fight for them, I'd like a list. I apparently am abnormal and prefer to fly to get from place to place.

Anyway, anyone know of any website with this info?

Comment: I was under the impression they all did. If not I generally use the Rebel call vehicle skill to spawn a chopper.

Comment: @DavidYell I don't think all of them do from what I remember.  Also they said *spawn points*, I assume they mean the places that you can fast travel to since you can spawn pretty much anywhere after dying.  But using the rebel vehicle drop was a god sent for this game.

Comment: Yes, any outpost represented with a small house icon.

Comment: Incorrect, I'd say only about half of the rebel hideouts have them. Cities/villages seem to have them much more often.

I never thought of using rebel dropoff -- actually, I just checked and realised you can choose which type of vehicle you want. I guess problem is solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I tried @timmy_jim 's suggestion numerous times, and I find that typically requesting a chopper ends up in me either having to sprint way too far, or it sliding into a tree/pole/rock and being unusable.

So here is my list. Please feel free to comment if I missed a rally point, or if one is incorrect. (Edit: please note that these only apply if you've unlocked 3 of the vehicle drop-off missions for the rebels.)

**agua verde**

 alpha        y

 bravo        n

 charlie    y

 delta        y


**barvechos**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        n
 
charlie    n


**caimanes**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        n
 
charlie    y
 
delta        n
 
echo        y


**espiritu santo**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        n
 
charlie    n
 
delta        n


**flor de oro**

 alpha        y
 
bravo        y
 
charlie    n


**inca camina**
  
alpha        n

  bravo        n
  
charlie    n
  
delta        n
  
echo        y


**itacua**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        y
 
charlie    n
 
delta        y
 
echo        y


**koani**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        y

 charlie    n

 delta        y


**la cruz**

 alpha        y

 bravo        n


**libertad**

 alpha        y

 bravo        n

 charlie    y


**malca**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        y
 
charlie    y
 
delta        y


**media luna**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        n


**mojocoyo**
 
alpha        n
 
bravo        y


**monte puncu**
 
alpha        n
 
bravo        y


**montuyoc**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        n
 
charlie    y


**ocoro**
 
alpha        n
 
bravo        n
 
charlie    y
 
delta        y


**pucara**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        y
 
charlie    y
 
delta        n


**remanzo**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        n


**san mateo**
 
alpha        n
 
bravo        y


**tabacal**
 
alpha        y
 
bravo        n
 
charlie    n


**villa verde**
 
alpha        n
 
bravo        y
 
charlie    n

Comment: I forgot to delete the echo rally point in Malca; it does not exist. (I originally put alpha through echo on all the "states", then checked them out individually until last night, where I closed up the last ones I hadn't visited while playing and I guess I missed it. But I guess I can't edit the post, or something. So it's just left blank: it's not an actual rally point.

Answer (score 1):

Nice list. Aditionally, if you want to take the 2 seats attack choppers (the ones with a Cobra model, that the game calls "Apaches"). These are the 7 locations:

- Koani, Combat Outpost (-14.01 -66.46)
- Media Luna, F.O.B Buitre
- Media Luna, M.O.B Condor
- Libertad, F.O.B Oso Hormiguero
- Flor De Oro, Combat Outpost (-19.38 -61.43)
- Flor De Oro, M.O.B Jaguar
- Flor De Oro, F.O.B Serpiente